# Adding a wider icon to a WPF Window Titlebar

Tags: c#, wpf, window, icons, titlebar

I want to add an icon to the WPF window titlebar, but my icon is a bit wider than the fixed size of the icons accepted by the titlebar (16x16) Is there any way to add a wider icon to the titlebar?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, because Windows handles the standard window chrome. You have to do a custom window and replace the chrome. [For example this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/121576-c%23-wpf-custom-title-bar-tutorial/) or look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30062/WPF-Non-Client-Area-Design-Techniques-For-Custom-W).